# Securing application with AspectJ vs SpringInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, api, security, aspectj

This is a very tricky question, and I know it. Well, I'll do my best to clarify it.

I'm writing an API in Spring secured under JWTs and OAuth2 and I don't want to use the Spring Security layer. In other words, I want to create my own security layer with my own rules, etc...

That said, I've found two options to create this layer web abroad.

- AspectJ
- Spring Interceptors

---

### AspectJ

With AspectJ I can create an aspect to wrap every method annotated with `@MySecurityAnnotation(role="bar", permission="foo", group="blah")` and grant that no user would invoke the `joinPoint` without the correct permission.

With this approach, the code got obfuscated because the AspectJ inject code to the *.class* final files. (please, correct me if I'm saying nonsense). On the other hand, I don't need to verify via reflection for the annotated types because the code is already wrapped.

---

### Spring Interceptor

With the interceptor, as the name says, is created a single point of interception for every `HandlerMethod` and now I need to check in every request if the request points to a `HandlerMethod` as it should be in order to verify the users credentials.

So *I think* that this is slowly then the AspectJ implementation, because we need to check via reflection for the annotated methods to get the roles/permissions needed to access the endpoint.

---

Ok, I've explained both scenarios, now I just want to know which one would be the best and in which situation. There's someone who spend hours thinking about that, like me? Is there any other implementation not listed? Is there a better way to implement security in a Spring API without Spring Security layer? Please let me know.

Thanks for all that help.

Comment: The best would be to not reinvent your security framework. Which to use depends on what you want to secure, if you want to secure services there is no `HandlerInterceptor` that will help you. AspectJ is also applied using proxies when using Spring unless you configure compile timeweaving. However as mentioned don't try to reinvent a security framework there are plenty out there use those instead. Generally they do more then just role/group based access.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum I'm reading some articles about Apache Shiro. What do you recomend to me?

Comment: I'm biased towards Spring Security as it integrates reallly nice, but Apache Shiro also has Spring integration.

Comment: @M.Deinum is basically right, but expressed technical detail in a way easy to misunderstand about AspectJ: **Spring AOP** is based on dynamic proxies. **AspectJ** however, about which the OP was talking (hint: modified class files) is not, no matter if used via compile-time weaving, as M. Deinum said, nor via load-time weaving, which is the usual way Spring users apply AspectJ and is described well in the Spring manual. So with LTW you can keep your original class files (even though I would argue that the AspectJ compiler does not "obfuscate" them) and have the full power of AspectJ.

Comment: AspectJ when used with Spring still uses the same Spring AOP infrastructure. AspectJ is applied the same as regular aopalliance interceptors. It will only change if you yourself configure compile-timeweaving OR loadtimeweaving. The latter isn't enabled by default and all AOP is thus by default (regardless of the way of expression the AOP) by proxies.